# How can I configure the Visual Studio 2019 to stay at 16.4 servicing baseline and avoid update to 16.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Microsoft announced that the [Visual Studio 2019 16.4 version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tis-the-season-visual-studio-2019/) is a long term servicing version:

> Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 is the second supported servicing
>   baseline for Visual Studio 2019. Consequently, Enterprise and
>   Professional customers needing to adopt a long term stable and secure
>   development environment are encouraged to standardize on this version.
>   As explained in more detail in our lifecycle and support policy,
>   version 16.4 will be supported with fixes and security updates for one
>   year after the release of the next servicing baseline.

Inside Visual Studio 2019 I get the notification for the 16.5.2

[image]

but I want to update to 16.4.7. In options dialog I can't find a way to tell VS to stay at 16.4.x.

What is the magic here? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution on my own. There is indeed no option to stay at 16.4 inside the IDE. You have to download the [latest installer each time from https://my.visualstudio.com](https://my.visualstudio.com/downloads?Visual%20Studio%202019%20version%2016.4):

[image]

and run the offered installer. Here the Update to next 16.4 version is shown and installable:

[image]

To summarize, each time VS2019 offers a new Update check the [release notes page for 16.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.4) if there is an update for 16.4, too and download the new installer to update to next 16.4 patch.