# Visual Studio 2019: Debugger shows incomplete vector variable information

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

**The issue**

Working in C++, VS 2019 Professional 16.0.4.

Whilst in debug, when hovering over a variable you usually get a tool-tip, which is expandable for vectors showing their contents.
In my case this tool-tip is not expandable. 
Also, the bigger problem is that adding the specified variable to watch or using the quick watch/Locals/Autos windows, I see missing elements in the expanded vector:

[image: Autos Window Expanded Vector]

Using the immediate window to see variable contents works fine, but it is a bit cumbersome.

**What I tried:**

- Tried deleting the .vs folder, with no luck.
- Trying to reproduce in a small console application does not work.
- Tried to update, Installer says it's the latest version of VS.
- "Repair VS installation"
- Clean & Rebuild

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you building in a release configuration or debug?

Comment: Upgrade VS Studio to a newer version. Maybe it's a bug that has been fixed. The latest version is 16.5.4.

Comment: Did it use to work before? If so, did it change for all projects?

Comment: I'm building in debug mode. And, yes, this used to work before, it actually stopped working after re-installing VS.

Comment: VS Installer says it is the latest version - I noticed the newer version on the MS website, I'll try to see if the installer itself needs an update

Comment: 16.0.4 is very old, if you need to stay at 16.0, get lastest [16.0.13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.0#16.0.13) installer similar to my [16.4 way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359432/1466046)

Comment: Thank you, @magicandre1981! I'll give it a try and let you know.